# If I have a string "4 2 66" how can i get the ints 4, 2, 66 in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this string `"4 2 66"` and i want to convert it into ints and then assign the numbers into variables `A = 4, B = 2, N = 66` how can I do it ? is there any function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function, but you can use `map`:

```
>>> s = "4 2 66"
>>> a, b, n = map(int, s.split())
>>> a
4
>>> b
2
>>> n
66
```

`s.split()` will take your string and turn it into a list, where each item is string separated by space:

```
>>> s.split()
['4', '2', '66']
```

Now, we want to turn the *string* `'4'` into the integer `4` - to do that we use the built-in `int` function.

`map` is a way to apply a function to each object of a collection. So `map(int, s.split())` means "apply the `int` function for each item returned by the `s.split()` function".

The final task is to assign each value to a variable. To do that we use [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
str1 = "4 2 22"
A,B,N = [int(i) for i in str1.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve via map or iterator after splitting as shown below

```
str = "4 2 66"
A, B, N = map(int, str.split())
```

or

```
str = "4 2 66"
A, B, N = [int(x) for x in str.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A,B,N= "4 2 66".split(" ")
```

Quick solution.

Comment: The question says that they have to be converted into ints